# Where and how to use listener for two buttons?

Tags: java

I want to add listeners to the two Inventory and Statistics buttons to open new frames. I've been looking all around and can't seem to understand where to put them under what circumstances and why none of the ones I've tried even work.

Where should I place them/it in order to get the buttons to work correctly?

**Incassable.java**

```
class Incassable extends tiles { 
 public static void main(String args[]) { 
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setResizable(false);
  JPanel main = new JPanel();
  GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0,15);
  GridLayout bot = new GridLayout(0,2);  
  main.setLayout(grid);
  frame.add(main,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

  int[][] map = {
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }
};  
  createMap(main, map);

  JPanel menu = new JPanel();
  menu.setLayout(bot);
  frame.add(menu,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
  JButton inv = new JButton("Inventory");
  JButton stats = new JButton("Statistics");
  menu.add(inv);
  menu.add(stats);

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

**tiles.java**

```
public class tiles {
    public static void addGrass(JPanel panel, int amount) {
      for (int n = 0; n < amount; n++) {
       ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("grass.png");
       JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
       panel.add(label);
      }
    }

public static void addBlack(JPanel panel, int amount) {
  for (int n = 0; n < amount; n++) {
   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("black.jpg");
   JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
   panel.add(label);
  }
}

public static void createMap(JPanel panel, int[][] map) {
    for (int n = 0; n < map.length; n++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 15; k++) {
          if (map[n][k] == 0) { addGrass(panel,1); }
          if (map[n][k] == 1) { addBlack(panel,1); }
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: [A JButton listener example](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jbutton-listener-pressed-actionlistener)

Comment: Thank you so much!